# An equation to solve in natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Some clues needed for the equation

$$(3+\sqrt{2})^x-(5-3\sqrt{2})^y=6+9\sqrt{2}, \quad x,y \in \mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $(3+\sqrt2)^2=11+6\sqrt2$

Comment: Then $y=1$ gives $(2,1)$ solution.

Comment: @Abrilliantkid: That’s right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, is the unique solution?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott is this the unique solution?

Comment: @Abrilliantkid: I don’t know: I’ve not tried for a general solution. If I were to try, I’d let $(3+\sqrt2)^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt2$, set up recurrences for $a_n$ and $b_n$, do the same sort of thing for $(5-3\sqrt2)^n=c_n+d_n\sqrt2$, and try to see whether the system $a_n=c_m+6,b_n=d_m+9$ has any other solutions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ok. Thank you.

Comment: @Abrilliantkid: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to solve in natural numbers, notice that $0 < 5 - 3\sqrt{2} < 1$. This implies that $ 0 < ( 5 - 3 \sqrt{2} ) ^ y < 1$, and hence

$$6 + 9 \sqrt{2} < (3 + \sqrt{2} )^x < 7 + 9 \sqrt{2} $$

This forces $x = 2$, from which $y = 1$ (from Brian).

Comment: Oh, this is really nice.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't generalize (which shouldn't be surprising).